# In ES6, how do you pass in extra arguments to a function inside a .then() call?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

If I have the following setup:

```
function entryPoint (someVariable) {

  getValue(arg)
    .then(anotherFunction)
}

function anotherFunction (arg1) {
}
```

How can I make `someVariable` available in `anotherFunction`?

Comment: Use a normal closure: `getValue(arg).then(result => anotherFunction(someVariable))`

Answer (score 1):

You could try this.

```
function entryPoint (someVariable) {
  getValue(arg)
    .then(anotherFunction(someVariable))
}

function anotherFunction(someVariable) {
  return function(arg1) {
  }
}
```

Comment: I was wondering if there was some way to do it with bind, call, or apply?

Comment: @Daniel you can, `.then(anotherFunction.bind(null,someVariable));`, note though you will have to modify the function definition ie `anotherFunction(someVar,arg1){}` as the bound variable will come before other passed arguments.

Comment: Binding and then reordering the arguments of anotherFunction worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can pass extra arguments with `.bind`, if you want to pass the context, don't use `null` and pass `this` or something else instead. But after you pass the context, pass the other values that you expect as params within `anotherFunction`.

```
function entryPoint (someVariable) {

  getValue(arg)
    .then(anotherFunction.bind(null, 1, 2))
}

function anotherFunction (something, other, arg1) {
  // something = 1
  // other = 2
  // the returned value from the promise will be set to arg1
}
```